# Why use a GitHub template instead of a fork?

Tags: git, github

Lately, I jumped into [an e-commerce UI template from Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ecommerce-ui-template/getting-started/react/). According to GitHub, I can either fork the repository or use it as a template. The difference seems to be that a template is not made for fetching the upstream of the original repository. I am a bit confused about why I should use it as a template when I pretty much lose access to future updates. Should I not just fork the repository instead and potentially get some neat updates?

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-a-repository-from-a-template, which explains the differences?

Comment: I understand that it is convenient to have a fresh commit history and all that, but why does using a template restrict the user from fetching the upstream of the original repository? It would seem handy to me to get some updates. I guess that it would mess up the fresh commit history?

Comment: You can't have both. Nothing would stop you adding the upstream remote and cherry-picking applicable commits, but how long are you going to keep the your repo close enough to the template for them to apply cleanly anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel like I know enough now. It might indeed be a total nightmare to adapt to a completely new version of the template.

Comment: The reason you cannot have both is a technical issue that is intimately tied to Git's internal structure for commits. I myself would almost always use a fork (I see little value to GitHub's peculiar template system) and where I didn't use a fork I'd probably clone the original repository, use filter-branch or filter-repo, and turn that into my clone rather than using GitHub's peculiar template system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between a fork and a template is that when you fork it's meant to contribute to the parent repository. Here are some of the pros/cons of each

## Fork

### Pros

- Be able to fetch upstream
- Able to open PRs to contribute to the head repository.

### Cons

- Some features like visibility are unable to be changed.

---

## Templates

### Pros

- Can change all settings

### Cons

- Unable to fetch upstream
- Able to open PRs to contribute to the head repository.

Comment: Note that this isn't actually true though. A fork is not "meant to contribute to the parent", it's just a fork, so it lets you send PRs to the parent. Also, because fetching is a `git` opreation, not a github-specific thing, you can _always_ fetch from _any_ upstream as long as you added their repo as a remote.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I do know that fetching is not specific to Github but there wasn't a point including making the head repo a remote since the OP is talking specifically about Github.